# Rails 5 query using Pluck how do I format created_at to be date only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this query which returns rows of created_at datetimes and a value, I would like the datetime to be just date.  I can't work out how to use any of the datetime format options in this style of query.  Any help appreciated.

```
@channels_counts_for_history_graph = Count.where(channel_id: 
current_channel).pluck("counts.created_at", "counts.followers")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use date function from sql command

```
@channels_counts_for_history_graph = Count.where(channel_id: 
current_channel).pluck("date(counts.created_at)", "counts.followers")
```